# best method to choose to save huge data from excel to Sql

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an Excel file from which I have to extract the required data and save it to a database. I know by using `Range` we can get a particular range of data. But my data that was to be extracted was a bit large. So can anyone suggest which was the best and simple method to retrieve the data and store the information in a database?

I would like to read the data from `A10` to an unknown range. My data will be as follows

[image]

As per marked with red after that data should go in to the database `column` by `column` I will do that if anyone can suggest the best method to read the remaining columns too.

Comment: What is in `A10`? Everything selected in red?

Comment: The data that i had to read will start from `A10`.. The selected region should go to the table initially, after that the next 5 lines of data like that i would like to store the whole data at a time in to my table

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - is `A10` the cell that has **A A MILNE EL** in it?

Comment: Yeah the text in `A10` is `A A MILNE EL` as per u said

Comment: A nice flat file would be much easier too manage. Also which RDMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still need to do it from code there is only one way of doing. As per your question you said that your data will start from `A10`, first of all get the `UsedRange` of `excel` as follows

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
```

As there are only 2 `columns` get the `row count` and `column count` of excel ad follows

```
iRows = xlRange.Rows.Count;
iCols = xlRange.Columns.Count;
```

Later start your loop as follows

```
for (int iRow = 10; iRow <= iRows; iRow++)
 {
   for (int iCol = 1; iCol <= iCols; iCol++)
   {
      xlRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[iRow, iCol];
      Console.WriteLine(xlRange.Text); // From here do as per you required and insert the required data to the data base. 
      List<string> lstItems = new List<string>(); // Declare this initially 
       lstItems.Add(xlRange.Text.ToString());
       if (lstItems.Count == 10)
       {
         if (xlRange.Text.ToString().Contains("www") || lstItems[9].ToString() == string.Empty)
         {
         }
      }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer , but as i said i would like to insert the data after `www.something.org` to the database. how can i achieve this. Some times there will be blank data in that place..

Answer (score 2):

You could use SQL Server Integration Services to import the excel data to a table.  A SSIS package can run at scheduled times or be invoked. It uses the spreadsheet as a data source and allows you to map columns.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) to read in the Excel file and parse it any way you want. We use it to import large Excel files into a SQL database as well. Using NPOI you have complete freedom on how to interpret the data.

Most important thing is that, if you want to do this more often, either the format of the Excel file should not change, or you should have some generic description of the Excel file stored somewhere else which tells your code how to interpret the file. The latter is of course more difficult to do. It depends on your particular use case which is better.

In our case the Excel file has a fixed layout, so our implementation is based on that layout.